# Laravel Valet Not Detecting Git Cloned Project

Tags: php, git, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.4

I'm new Laravel and am using Valet as per the Laracasts video. I get that Valet works great with site we instantiate locally, however I cloned my project that I started at home and valet is not running it or at least correctly. Once I did "composer install" it started to show some signs of life, but ended up with thison my screen: "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

What am I doing wrong? How do I even debug or check logs?

Please help!

-V

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Some ideas here if you search for "GIT" you get instructions to make sure you 1. Have the latest Valet and 2. Restart it https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your project folder and run the following commands:

```
composer install
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
```

Why? Because you need an .env file and a valid key, otherwise laravel always returns a 500 http error.

Extra Note: You only need to run php artisan migrate if you need tables and configured your .env file in the right way (host/database name and so on)

Comment: This is the right Example, and totally solved my problem!
However what I would urge you to edit, just to take it that extra step, is to add the note that if you've already setup a DB else where you will need to make those mods to the .env that mirror your database.php, so you may connect to the db if remote, otherwise spin an new one then migrate. Just as a tip to newbie who may not realize it.

Great job!

Answer (score 1):

This an error 500, it can be produced by many reasons. I suggest you check the following:

- Create a .env file at the root of your Laravel project and set it up following the instructions of the repo you cloned, normally this file is not versioned and you should create by yourself.
- Check the permissions of your `storage` folder, you can run `chmod -R 755 storage` at the root of your project to be sure.